# IIS 7.5 ,single IP single SSL two sites

Tags: iis, ssl, ip

I have two sites with single IP ( 10.10.0.1) two different domains( xyz.com and abc.com )and one SSL ( for xyz.com) on a IIS 7.5 server . I have no problem in getting both sites on http also https works fine for xyz.com if I try to access https:// abc.com it shows the ssl for xyz.com which i dont want , is there a way to block https abc.com ? I could not find any similar issues posted around , even though there are solution for single ip , multiple SSL sites.

Comment: did you check the SSL Settings? Require SSL should be unchecked for abc.com

Comment: thanks Hari , site abc.com dose not have an SSL binding , as it dose not required to run under SSL, so require SSL under IIS is greyed out

Comment: Turn off binding to port 443 for abc.